# XSD Schema for optical media

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xsd

I recently wrote my first XSD Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="mediums">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="medium" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:token" />
                    <xs:element name="releaseDate" type="xs:date" />
                    <xs:element name="mediumType">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:enumeration value="CD"/>
                                <xs:enumeration value="DVD"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="length" type="length">
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="attributes">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice>
                                <xs:element name="actor" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:token"/>
                                        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="track" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:token"/>
                                        <xs:element name="artist" type="xs:token"/>
                                        <xs:element name="length" type="length"/>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>    
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:positiveInteger"    use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

<!-- Represents a minute or a second value !-->
        <xs:simpleType name="max60Integer">
            <xs:restriction base="positiveInteger">
                <xs:maxExclusive value="60" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:complexType name="length">
            <xs:element name="hours" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="minutes" type="max60Integer"/>
            <xs:element name="seconds" type="max60Integer"/>
        </xs:complexType>
```

It should represent following classes:

> ```cs
> public enum MediumType {DVD, CD}
>
> sealed class Medium : IEquatable<Medium>
> {
>     public static bool operator ==(Medium medium1,Medium medium2)
>     {
>         if ((object)medium1 == null||(object)medium2 == null)
>         {
>             return Object.Equals(medium1, medium2);
>         }           
>         return medium1.Equals(medium2) ? true : false;
>     }
>     public static bool operator !=(Medium medium1,Medium medium2)
>     {
>         if ((Object)medium1 == null || (Object)medium2 == null) return !Object.Equals(medium1, medium2);
>         return !medium1.Equals(medium2);
>
>     }
>     public bool Equals(Medium medium)
>     {
>         if (medium == null) return false;
>         if (this.Name != medium.Name)
>             return false;
>         if (this.Length != medium.Length)
>             return false;
>         if (this.ReleaseTime != medium.ReleaseTime)
>             return false;
>         return new HashSet<IAttribute>(Attributes).SetEquals(medium.Attributes);
>
>     }
>     public override bool Equals(object obj)
>     {
>         if (obj == null) return false;
>         Medium medium = obj as Medium;
>         if (medium == null) return false;
>         else return Equals(medium);
>     }
>
>     public override int GetHashCode()
>     {
>         return Name.GetHashCode();
>     }
>     public override string ToString()
>     {
>         string classtype = Enum.GetName(typeof(MediumType),CurrentMediumType);
>         return string.Format("{0} Name={1} Length={2} ReleaseTime={3}",classtype,Name,Length,ReleaseTime.Month+"."+ReleaseTime.Year);
>     }
>     public IAttribute this[int index]
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return Attributes[index];
>         }
>             set
>         {
>             Attributes[index] = value;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public Medium(string name,int length,DateTime releaseTime,MediumType mediumtype,long id)
>     {
>         this.Name = name;
>         this.Length = length;
>         this.ReleaseTime = releaseTime;
>         this._mediumType = mediumtype;
>         this.Attributes = new List<IAttribute>();
>         ID = id;
>     }
>     public long ID { get; }
>     private MediumType _mediumType;
>
>     public MediumType CurrentMediumType
>     {
>         get { return _mediumType; }
>     }
>
>     public List<IAttribute> Attributes { get; set; }
>
>
>
>     private string _name;
>
>     public string Name
>     {
>         get { return _name; }
>         set { if(value != null && value != "")
>             {
>                 _name = value;
>             }
>         else
>             {
>                 throw new Exception("A Medium must have a name!");
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     private int _length;
>
>     public int Length
>     {
>         get { return _length; }
>         set {
>             if (value < 0)
>                 throw new Exception("The length of the film must be over 0!");
>             else
>                 _length = value;
>         }
>     }
>
>     private DateTime _releaseTime;
>
>     public DateTime ReleaseTime
>     {
>         get { return _releaseTime; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (DateTime.Compare(value,DateTime.Now) <= 0)
>             {
>                 _releaseTime = value;
>             }
> else
>             {
>                 throw new Exception("The release time can not be in the  future!");
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>
>
> }
>
> //Actor
> public class Actor : IAttribute,IEquatable<Actor>
> {
>     public override int GetHashCode()
>     {
>         return Name.GetHashCode();
>     }
>     public override bool Equals(object obj)
>     {
>         if (obj == null) return false;
>         Actor actor1 = obj as Actor;
>         if (actor1 == null) return false;
>         return Equals(actor1);
>
>     }
>     public static bool operator ==(Actor actor1,Actor actor2)
>     {
>         if (actor1 == null || actor2 == null) return   Object.Equals(actor1, actor2);
>         return actor1.Equals(actor2);
>     }
>     public static bool operator !=(Actor actor1,Actor actor2)
>     {
>         return actor1 == actor2 ? false : true;
>     }
>     public bool Equals(Actor other)
>     {
>         if (other == null) return false;
>         if (this.Name != other.Name) return false;
>         if (this.Age != other.Age) return false;
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     private string _name;
>
>     public string Name
>     {
>         get { return _name; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (value != null && value != "")
>                 _name = value;
>             else
>                 throw new Exception("An actor needs an name!");
>         }
>     }
>     private int _age;
>
>     public int Age
>     {
>         get { return _age; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (value < 0)
>                 throw new Exception("A actor can't be jounger than 0!");
>             else if (value > 100)
>                 throw new Exception("The actor isn't older than 100, is he?");
>             else
>                 _age = value;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public Actor(string name,int age)
>         {
>         this.Name = name;
>         this.Age = age;
>     }
>
> public override string ToString()
>     {
>         return string.Format("Actor Name={0} Age={1}",Name,Age);
>     }
>
>
>
> }
> //Track
>  public class Track : IAttribute,IEquatable<Track>
> {
>     public override int GetHashCode()
>     {
>         return Name.GetHashCode();
>     }
>     public static bool operator ==(Track track1,Track track2)
>     {
>         if (track1 == null || track2 == null)
>             return Object.Equals(track1, track2);
>         return track1.Equals(track2);
>     }
>     public static bool operator !=(Track track1,Track track2)
>     {
>         return  track1 == track2 ? false : true ;
>     }
>         public override bool Equals(object obj)
>     {
>         if (obj == null) return false;
>         IAttribute attribut = obj as IAttribute;
>         if (attribut == null) return false;
>         return Equals(attribut);
>     }
>     public bool Equals(Track other)
>     {
>         if (other == null) return false;
>         if (other.Name != this.Name) return false;
>         if (other.Artist != this.Artist) return false;
>         if (other.Length != this.Length) return false;
>         return true;
>
>     }
>     private string _name;
>
>     public string Name
>     {
>         get { return _name; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (value != null && value != "")
>                 _name = value;
>             else
>                 throw new Exception("An track needs a name!");
>         }
>     }
>
>     private decimal _length;
>
>     public decimal Length
>     {
>         get { return _length; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (value > 0)
>                 _length = value;
>             else
>                 throw new Exception("The length can not be under 0 minutes.");
>
>         }
>     }
>     private string _artist;
>
>     public string Artist
>     {
>         get { return _artist; }
>         set
>         {
>             if (value != null && value != "")
>                 _artist = value;
>             else
>                 throw new Exception("A artist needs a name!");
>         }
>     }
>
>     public long ID { get;  }
>
>     public Track(string name,decimal length,string artist)
>     {
>         this.Name = name;
>         this.Length = length;
>         this.Artist = artist;
>
>     }
>     public override string ToString()
>     {
>         return string.Format("Track Name={0} Artist={1} Length={2}",Name,Artist,Length);
>     }
> }
> ```

I will have look at target namespace etc. For now it's just about the design of my schema.

Comment: So what do you want to be reviewed? The xsd schema, the C# model, or both?

Comment: The schema ;) The Code ist just to show you, what i tried to represent in the schema. Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: "It *should* represent the following classes" - *does it*? You can use `xsd.exe` to *generate* classes from your schema.

Comment: Okay. Is the quality the same, as in self coded schemas? I made bad experiences with generated things, but i will try it...

Answer (score 2):

I have to admit it's been (thankfully) a while since I worked with XSD.

A few random points:

- I would rename your `max60Integer` to "max59integer", since the maximum of 60 is excluded;
- Age is defined as a positive integer in your schema: `<xs:element name="age" type="xs:positiveInteger"/` - but your C# code allows it to be 0 (less restrictive than the schema), while disallowing it to exceed 100 (more restrictive than the schema). This is quite inconsistent.
- This is cosmetics, but I would close empty tags.

  Eg.

  ```
  <xs:element name="length" type="length">
  </xs:element>
  ```

  should become

  ```
  <xs:element name="length" type="length" />
  ```

---

Purely as a side note - since you didn't mean to submit your C# code for a review:

```cs
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) return false;
    Actor actor1 = obj as Actor;
    if (actor1 == null) return false;
    return Equals(actor1);
}
```

I know you've only posted it as a reference point, but I have to say I find it very unreadable.

`return` clauses on the same line as the condition aren't considered good practice, plus the first `if` is totally redundant: if `obj` is null, then obviously `obj as Actor` will return null anyway. I'm also not sure what the ordinal is supposed to achieve. This method could be simplified to something way clearer imho:

```cs
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    Actor actor = obj as Actor;
    return actor != null && Equals(actor);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i will fix it. Forgot that as can handle null values...